# Ajax-solr init load

Tags: ajax, solr, init

i try to use ajax-solr and my autocomplete and result work. 
But i have problem on first load. 
I would like to delete the first request on all index.
Because i would like to see only my searchbar on my page.

I didn't find where is problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the ajax-solr Reuters tutorial, then you probably have a Manager.doRequest() call after you initialize the widgets, etc. Just remove that line to not send the first request.